# Change a label text that it's declared after my ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, awt, label, actionlistener

What I'm trying to do here is that every time that i press a button and select an image the 
text of a label changes to the path of that image.

Here's my code:

```
public Frame() {
    setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 640, 480);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Select image");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
        {
            FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Image", "jpg", "jpeg");
            final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
            filec.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
            filec.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
            filecc.showDialog(Frame.this, "Select an image");
            File pathh = fc.getSelectedFile();
            String pathhs;
            pathhs = pathh.getPath();
            System.out.println("The path is: " + pathhs);   
            lblNewLabel.setText(pathhs) <--the problem 

        }
    });
    btnNewButton.setBounds(25, 408, 165, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnNewButton);


    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("New label");
    lblNewLabel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    lblNewLabel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 68, 266, 234);
    contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);       
}
```

The problem is in here:

```
                String pathhs;
                pathhs = pathh.getPath();
                System.out.println("The path is: " + pathhs);   
                lblNewLabel.setText(pathhs) <--the problem
```

I don't have access to the variable `lblNewLabel` therefore I cant change the text.

Comment: You need to create a label **before** you can change it.

Comment: Stop using `setBounds` and start using a layout manager

Answer (score 1):

You can reference local variables from anonymous classes, so long as they have been declared with the `final` modifier before the anonymous class is defined.

So, I'd modify your code to something like:

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Select image");
btnNewButton.setBounds(25, 408, 165, 23);
contentPane.add(btnNewButton);


final JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("New label");
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
    {
        // Your actionPerformed implementation...
    }
});

lblNewLabel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
lblNewLabel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 68, 266, 234);
contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't have access to the variable lblNewLabel therefore I cant change the text.

Define the label as a class variable not a local variable, then the anonymous inner class can access the variable.

Comment: thank you all specially camickr.
all i had to do was:

final JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("New label");